# Approach shopping cart storage, database with sessionID

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, shopping-cart

Just to be clear, I'm going to store my shopping cart in a database.
It's just that I would like information regarding the details on how to store it exactly.

I have the following structure for my shopping cart and orders:
[image: shopping cart]

First of all, is this technically a good approach?

- **A product is added to a cart with the sessionID, date and amount.**
  *Do I add another table or rename the table given that it's not really carts but more collection of products from different carts?*

  - **When a user wants to order his products we place them in the order_items table. When the user selects purchase his order is placed in the orders table.**

Is this a good approach, are there better ones?

P.S.: the user doesn't need to be registered to place an order.

Comment: Nobody has a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is have an intermediate table, something like ProductsInCart, with three columns, ProductID, CartID, and Quantity. ProductID keys into Products, CartID keys into Carts, and quantity is simply a positive integer.

Comment: That's what I've decided to do as well.